# Removing blank lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr, blank-line

I have a csv file in which every other line is blank. I have tried everything, nothing removes the lines. What should make it easier is that the the digits 44 appear in each valid line. Things I have tried:

```
grep -ir 44 file.csv
sed '/^$/d' <file.csv
cat -A file.csv
sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d' <file.csv
egrep -v "^$" file.csv
awk 'NF' file.csv
grep '\S' file.csv
sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d; /^\s*$/d' <file.csv
cat file.csv | tr -s \n
```

Decided I was imagining the blank lines, but import into Google Sheets and there they are still! Starting to question my sanity! Can anyone help?

Comment: Could it be an issue with line endings (DOS / Unix / Mac)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-i` option to replace the original file with the edited one.

```
sed -i '/^[ \t]*$/d' file.csv
```

Alternatively output to another file and rename it, which is doing the exactly what `-i` does.

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' file.csv > file.csv.out && mv file.csv.out file.csv
```

Comment: Nice, though it should be noted that the 1st solution requires _GNU_ `sed`. You can make the 2nd solution _portable_ by replacing `[ \t]` with `[[:blank:]]`.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for this informative comment. I'll change it immediately!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n -i '/44/p' file
```

-n means skip printing
  -i inplace (overwrite same file)
  - /44/p print lines where '44' exists

without '44' present

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file
```

\s is matching whitespace, ^startofline, $endofline, d delete line

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat bl.txt
Line 1 (next line has a tab)

Line 2 (next has several space)

Line 3
```

You can remove blank lines with Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'print unless /^\s*$/' bl.txt
Line 1 (next line has a tab)
Line 2 (next has several space)
Line 3
```

awk:

```
$ awk 'NF>0' bl.txt
Line 1 (next line has a tab)
Line 2 (next has several space)
Line 3
```

sed + tr:

```
$ cat bl.txt | tr '\t' ' ' | sed '/^ *$/d'
Line 1 (next line has a tab)
Line 2 (next has several space)
Line 3
```

Just sed:

```
$ sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' bl.txt
Line 1 (next line has a tab)
Line 2 (next has several space)
Line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your commands do not show that you capture their *output* in a *new* file to be used *in place of the original*, there's nothing wrong with them, EXCEPT that:

```
cat file.csv | tr -s \n
```

should be:

```
cat file.csv | tr -s '\n'  # more efficient alternative: tr -s '\n' < file.csv
```

Otherwise, the *shell* eats the `\` and all that `tr` sees is `n`.

Note, however, that the above only eliminates only truly *empty* lines, whereas some of your other commands also eliminate *blank* lines (empty or all-whitespace).

Also, the `-i` (for case-insensitive matching) in `grep -ir 44 file.csv` is pointless, and while using `-r` (for recursive searches) will not change the fact that only `file.csv` is searched, it *will* prepend the filename followed by `:` to each matching line.

---

If you have indeed captured the output in a new file and *that* file truly still has blank lines, the `cat -A` (`cat -et` on BSD-like platforms) you already mention in your question should show you if any unusual characters are present in the file, in the form of `^<char>` sequences, such as `^M` for `\r` chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you like `awk`, this should do:

```
awk '/44/' file
```

It will only print lines that contains `44`